# Handling Values of dynamic TextInput in react native

Tags: dynamic, react-native, react-native-ios, textinput

I'm a beginner to react. Right now I'm trying to add dynamic TextInputs based on server data, I'm having trouble getting data of each text fields. Below is my current code

```
renderData() {
    var questionArray = getDataFromServer();

    var lIndex = -1;
    const views = questionArray.map((item, index) => {
      if (item === "__TEXT__") {
        lIndex++;
        return (
          <LineInput
            placeholder=""
            onChangeText={text => this.onTextChanged(lIndex, text)}
            value={this.state.otherText[lIndex]}
            key={index}
          />
        );
      }
      return <Text key={index}>{item + " "}</Text>;
    });
    return views;
  }


onTextChanged = (index, value) => {
    console.log("Text Index:" + index);
    const Textdata = [...this.state.otherText]; 
    Textdata[index] = value;

    this.setState(
      {
        otherText: Textdata
      },
      () => {
        console.log("Text data = " + this.state.otherText);
      }
    );
  };
```

And this is my LineInput.js file

```
import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, TextInput } from "react-native";

const LineInput = ({
  value,
  onChangeText,
  placeholder,
  secureTextEntry,
  keyboardType,
  autoCapitalize
}) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        autoCorrect={false}
        onChangeText={onChangeText}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        style={styles.input}
        secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
        value={value}
        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
        keyboardType={keyboardType}
        autoCapitalize={autoCapitalize}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: 150,
    borderColor: "black",
    borderBottomWidth: 1
  },
  input: {
    color: "black",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "white",
    fontSize: 14
  }
});

export { LineInput };
```

Now the problem is no matter in which field I start typing, all data enters at the last text field. The log always displays the Text index as the last index and in the Text data, all data enters at the last item in the array. Am I doing something wrong here, if so, what would be the correct way to approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line

```
onChangeText={text => this.onTextChanged(lIndex, text)}
```

This doesn't "fix" the function to call when text changes. In other words, in this render cycle `lIndex` already has a fixed value (the index of the last input), and whenever `onChangeText` function is called on any of the inputs, the above line is interpreted with `lIndex`'s current value, and re-render happens afterwards, hence only the last input field changes.

How you go about solving this is up to you, I would suggest using an another way of indexing your inputs, so that the same variable `lIndex` is not used for all of them, or forcing a re-render before calling that function.

Comment: I'm out of ideas on how to do that. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Sure, the simplest solution would be to add `var i = lindex` below the `lindex++` line, and then use `i` instead of `lindex` in the following lines. Try this out and let me know if it works.

Comment: It's better to use index from questionArray mapping for proper binding.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best solution

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput } from 'react-native';

class Information extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: {
        name: null,
        address: null,
        school: null,
      },
    };
  }
//handle the text inputs in this format

handleText = (key, text) => {
    var input = { ...this.state.input };

    input[key] = text;
    console.log('INPUT', input);
    this.setState({ input });
  };
 render(){
  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
            placeholder='Hello'
            label='school'
            onChangeText={(text) => this.handleText('school', text)}
            value={this.state.input.school}
          />
          <TextInput
            placeholder='Hello'
            label='name'
            onChangeText={(text) => this.handleText('name', text)}
            value={this.state.input.name}
          />
          <TextInput
            placeholder='Hello'
            label='address'
            onChangeText={(text) => this.handleText('address', text)}
            value={this.state.input.address}
          />
    </View>
  )
 }
}

export default Information;
```